# fastest way to check if all elements of a list of strings is in a string

Tags: python, string, search, string-matching

I have a string

> "My name is Andrew, I am pretty awesome".

Lets say I have a list of lists such as

> [['andrew', 'name', 'awesome'], ['andrew', 'designation', 'awesome']]

I need my solution to return

> ['andrew', 'name', 'awesome']

The naive solution is :

```
myString='My name is Andrew, I am pretty awesome'
keywords = [['andrew', 'name', 'awesome'], ['andrew', 'designation', 'awesome']]
results=[]
for i in keywords:
 if all(substring in myString.lower() for substring in i):
    results.append(i)
print results
```

My issue is that when the list keywords is very very large (say 100000), there are performance bottlenecks. I need to know the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: create a set with the words you want to check, basically use `myString = set('My name is Andrew, I am pretty awesome'.split())`

Comment: Are you sure this code even works?

Comment: There is a typo on the second to last line. It should be `results` with an `s`. And btw you are returning a list of lists `[['andrew', 'name', 'awesome']]`

Comment: And you probably don't want that `print` statement inside the `for` loop.

Comment: and lowercase myString in  all function

Comment: Made a few changes to my answer, the please test these on your own data before deciding what to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Thanks to BlackBear for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278091/fastest-way-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-of-strings-is-in-a-string/48278215?noredirect=1#comment83540794_48278215) that my timings were skewed
>   because of the re-computation of loop invariants. On moving them out, things change, drastically.

There are two ways of doing this. The sane way, and the regex way. First, the setup.

```
string = "My name is Andrew, I am pretty awesome"
choices = [['andrew', 'name', 'awesome'], ['andrew', 'designation', 'awesome']]
```

**Option 1**
This one performs an `in` substring check inside a list comprehension. The `in` check runs on a modified implementation of the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) in C, and is very fast.

```
>>> [c for c in choices if all(y in string.lower() for y in c)]
[['andrew', 'name', 'awesome']]
```

And now, for the timings. But first, a minor performance nitpick; you can cache the value of `string.lower()` *outside* the loop, it's an invariant and doesn't need to be re-computed each time -

```
v = string.lower()
%timeit [c for c in choices if all(y in v for y in c)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop
```

---

**Option 2**
This one uses `re.split` + `set.issuperset`;

```
>>> import re
>>> [c for c in choices if set(re.split('\W', string.lower())).issuperset(c)] 
[['andrew', 'name', 'awesome']]
```

The use of `re.split` cannot be avoided, if you want to perform set checks, because of punctuation in your sentences.

Again, the `set` computation is a loop invariant, and can be moved out. This is how it does -

```
v = set(re.split('\W', string.lower()))
%timeit [c for c in choices if v.issuperset(c)] 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 µs per loop
```

This is an exceptional case where I find regular expressions performing marginally faster. However, these timings are not conclusive, because they vastly differ by the data's size and structure. I'd recommend trying things out with your own data before drawing any conclusions, although my gut feeling is that the regex solution would scale poorly.

Comment: Actually regexes are faster (on my machine, at least), but your code is slower because you build the set every time